# Shotwell: Videos have wrong date

Tags: video, shotwell

I'm new to Shotwell and imported my pictures. Some of the videos (apparently those I've shot with my smartphone) are now in a event dated to 1904, Jan 1st. I tried to edit the date, but the menu item (Photos->Adjust Time and Date) is unavailable for videos. Then I moved such a video into the correct event, but now the entire event is placed under 1904 and named "Fri Jan 1, 1904 - Sat Sep 11, 2010".

Comment: This is still here in Ubuntu Oneiric with Shotwell 0.11.3
The bug is NOT fixed. http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/4166
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shotwell/+bug/900501

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to set the date of a video in Shotwell 0.9.x.

But the good news is that this feature is already complete and will be in Shotwell 0.10!

Comment: Eric - the latest "answer" claims this is still an issue - can you clarify what the latest state of play is?

Comment: The links above are in regard to an issue with a specific camera and not necessary related to the question.